# How to find out which cron jobs are currently running?

Tags: 7, cron

Is this possible to find out which cron jobs are currently running?

Comment: What you meant by "which cron job" exactly ?

Comment: I want to know if there are any cron jobs running at the moment, possibly including a start time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be found in [drupal_cron_run](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7).  While it is the case that you can tell if Cron is currently running by calling `lock_acquire('cron', ...))`, just as Drupal does (don't forget to call lock_release too), Drupal does not in any way set any information about the individual cron hooks that it executes during a cron job.

If you need more control over cron job execution, you could always copy the drupal_cron_run function into your own module and modify it to suit.  drush_core_cron() does nothing other than call drupal_cron_run, so you could call your own cron function via drush ev 'mymodule_cron_run();' from your crontab.  If you did this, you would need to review the implementation of drupal_cron_run on every update of Drupal core, and check for any significant alterations in behavior, so you should only customize cron if it's really important that you do so.

Comment: And if you want to fire specific cron function (which is not recommended to do so IMO), just call MYMODULE_cron().